# Error in Android Gradle Plugin: "useAndroidX() should not be annotated with @Input"

Tags: flutter, androidx

I'm encountering an error in my Flutter project related to the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP). The error message is,

```
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript' (type 'RenderscriptCompile').
  - In plugin 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.RenderscriptCompile' method 'useAndroidX()' should not be annotated with: @Input.

    Reason: Input/Output annotations are ignored if they are placed on something else than a getter.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Remove the annotations.
      2. Rename the method.
```

I've checked my `build.gradle` file for the project, and for the app module, and I'm not explicitly using AndroidX dependencies in my project. I'm not sure why I'm encountering this error. How can I resolve it?

here is my relevant `android\build.gradle` file,

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here is the `app\build.gradle`,

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.shopx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I've already tried updating the Android Gradle Plugin and checking for AndroidX dependencies in my code.

Any assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

First I changed the `useAndroidX=false` in the `gradle.properties`,

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

I've also tried updating the Android Gradle Plugin and checking for AndroidX dependencies in my code.